# I can't choose primary or logical partition on Kubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, kubuntu

So I've been trying to install Kubuntu, my computer is a bit weird. My BIOS is UEFI apparently (it shows "Press F1 to Enter UEFI BIOS") but my Windows is on Legacy and MBR, now this wouldn't matter but I just can't install Kubuntu.
The first thing I did was prepare a 120GB unallocated space for Kubuntu, then I ran the Kubuntu installation, things were going smooth, I created the 4 partitions it asked for (root, home, swap and efi) until I got to the final part, in which it gave me a Fatal Error, where it said something along the lines "Failed to execute install GRUB on dev/sda/ THIS IS A FATAL ERROR" and then I got kicked out of the installation with the bug reports and yeah.

This happened some time ago when trying to install Mint, and what I did to fix it was set some partitions (iirc it was just the root partition) as primary, and it worked fine. But on Kubuntu I just can't find a way to choose "primary" or "logical" partition type! On the installation partition setup I can only choose the size, the beginning or end of the thing, the filesystem and the mount point! Please help, I just need to know how to do this on Kubuntu and it will much probably fix my issue.
Also, I tried installing the bootloader at dev/sda8 for the first time (sda8 was the efi partition), but that was just the first time and I got the error, then I tried again, this time on dev/sda/ which is the default (and I think it's also the most correct one) and it gave me the same thing. I doubt this is related though

EDIT: It did make my system unusable after the error, I tried to restart and GRUB rescue couldn't find a system or something like that. So after some time I just used Boot Repair on Kubuntu Live USB and I'm now using Windows, waiting for an answer so that I can install Kubuntu. And I didn't get the option to "Install alongside Windows 10", I only got some GUIDED options and the Manual one, which was what I used

Comment: Microsoft has required vendors to install Windows in UEFI boot mode to gpt partitioned drives. Why is Windows BIOS/MBR? If you still want Windows in BIOS boot mode, you have to install Kubuntu in BIOS boot mode, but if all 4 primary partitions are used, Windows converted drive to dynamic partitions or has fast start up on, you will still have issues. use ppa version with your live installer,
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: With a legacy setup for W10 (upgrades from legacy W7 can cause this), you should install Ubuntu in legacy mode, and since it doesn't care if the partition is logical or primary, free up space, make an extended partition, and Ubuntu should be able to install there on logical partitions. A second disk which you can boot directly may be in either mode (but if in UEFI, you won't be able to boot windows from it).